# HTML is not rendering single quotes

Tags: html, unicode

I have a DIV element where the Inner HTML is inserting

> &amp

into my Inner Text and it's getting rendered on the page.

**innerHTML**  And this exactly what gets rendered on the page:

```
backbone that helps you collaborate in the &amp;lsquo;we&amp;rsquo; space through the same familiar Outlook environment that you use in the &amp;lsquo;me&amp;rsquo; space.
```

However the InnerText is correct.

**innerText** (this is the actual string stored in the database.)

```
backbone that helps you collaborate in the &lsquo;we&rsquo; space.
```

The inner text renders fine when I run it in JSFiddle etc.
This happens in all browsers tested.

This is the actual div tag and it's also using angular:

[image: screenshot of element using chrome tools]

Comment: This question is screaming for a minimal, complete, verifiable example. At the very least, what browser are you using that *doesn't* process the entities?

Comment: Where are they _not_ rendering correctly?

Comment: What you've provided is insufficient to help you. Everything we see looks fine, so you'll need to work on adding details and hopefully providing a [mcve]

Comment: The provided HTML works fine for me, single quotes are displayed as expected.  Make sure you are using a browser that actually recognizes the `lsquo` and `rsquo` entities

Comment: Look at your Code Snippet more closely. The entities in the HTML are written as `&amp;lsquo;` and `&amp;rsquo;` instead of as `&lsquo;` and `&rsquo;`. That is why they are not being rendered correctly.  Your earlier Code Snippet did not replace `&` with `&amp;`, so that is why the entities rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
collaborate in the &amp;lsquo;we&amp;rsquo; space
```

Oops! I have a feeling that `&amp;` is **not** what you want.